# is there any way to select rows from a table without using offset or orderby?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to select rows from 10 million rows order by is expensive and offset is not very efficient. Is there any other way to do this in redshift

Comment: What is the criteria for the rows you want to select?  A random subset? All rows?

Comment: What is your end-goal? That is, why are you wanting to do this? Are you wanting to download the entire dataset, a bit at a time?

Comment: A bit at a time.

Comment: @BillWeiner i wanna extract a random subset

Comment: @JohnRotenstein end goal is get sample data from entire dataset. From 200million rows i need to extract 600 rows offset is taking a lot of time any efficient way to do it??

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to get a random sampling is to use the RANDOM() function to select a percentage of the rows.  Like this

```
select * 
from sales
order by random()
limit 10;
```

This may be what you are attempting to do and thus the question about "order by".  The issue is you have to reorder the entire table to get the subset / sample.

If you need a faster approach and don't have a true random sampling requirement then you can use some uncorrelated information in your table to sample the rows.  Let's say you have a timestamp with microsecond precision then you can use "where mod(microsecond_portion_of_timestamp, 100) = 1".  You will need to be sure that this information is "random" with respect of you table data.  If there are patterns to the microsecond portion then the result may not be random.  The upside of this approach is that it is fast.

If this isn't good enough and you want to avoid sorting you can use a where clause with random(). Like this

```
select a, b from (
  select a, b, random() as sample 
  from test) as sub
where sample < .01; -- return 1% of rows
```

This doesn't reorder the rows just calculates a "sample" (or not) value that is used to choose rows.  This process still needs to scan the entire table (read from disk) and calculate a random value for each row but doesn't sort on this random value.

You will notice that this process chooses a percent of rows (which you can adjust) and not a number of rows.  If you need a precise number of rows you can also sort on the random value and add a limit.  You will be sorting the rows but only a small percentage of the table.

```
select a, b from (
  select a, b, random() as sample 
  from test) as sub
where sample < .01
order by sample
limit 100;
```

In this example only 1% of the table is sorted by the random value.