# How to get a sample of random rows in redshift using SQL alchemy efficiently

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, alchemy

Theres a data set of size 200M how to get random sample data(of size 100rows) efficiently using SQLalchemy or any other possible way.

Comment: filter for 1 partition. otherwise you can't because redshift is columnar

Comment: please post the schema of the table.

Comment: How is this different to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73084062/is-there-any-way-to-select-rows-from-a-table-without-using-offset-or-orderby)?

Comment: Use `ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 100`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sales
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 10;
```

With random every row has an equal chance of being selected. Use Limit to choose how many rows to return.

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_RANDOM.html